# How to find specific database on a server

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

I am trying to locate one database from my database server. I have 22 different databases on the server. I am using:

```
select [name] from sys.databases
```

But this returns all the 22 names. I only need a specific one called "LightBulb".

Anyone knows by any chance? Meanwhile I will keep trying.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm a little confused - if you already know the exact name of the database, what's the point of the query?

Comment: in my program I am converting the SQL DB to a different file so I need to execute that particular database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select [name] from sys.databases where [name] = 'LightBulb';

Comment: I can can swear I have tried it and it gave me a column could be found error. Thank you so much.